# Find x in list of lists

Tags: list, haskell

I have a little problem with my homework to school. I have to write code, which will find any x (int or letter) in a list of lists.

I have something like this:

```
 find x xxs = [ [ x | x <- xs, x `elem` xs ] | xs <- xxs ]
```

Hugs98 accept it without any exception, but it doesn't work.

```
Input: find 2 [[1,1,1,1],[4,4,4,4],[3,3,3]]
Output: [[1,1,1,1],[4,4,4,4],[3,3,3,3]]
```

Comment: I don't know list comprehension, but this is how you could do it without: `find x = foldr (||) False . map (elem x)`

Comment: @Pubby `foldr (||) False` is just `or`

Comment: A problem with what you've written is that your inner list comprehension reads "I'd like all elements of a list that are elements of said list". That's a trivially true statement, and clearly not what you want. Pubby and is7s give a nice solution.

Comment: I'm just a beginner, sorry for that. Can you post me the full code by Pubby? Because when I'm trying it, I have an error:

    ERROR - Cannot find "show" function for:
    *** Expression : find2 2 [[1,1,1,1],[3,3,3,3],[4,4,4,4]]
    *** Of type    : [[Integer]] -> Bool

Comment: @Tomáš'Mada'Kurila: Pubby's function `find' x = or . (map (elem x))` works fine here (I've replaced the `foldr` bit with `or` as per is7s' comment). Its signature is `(Eq a) => a -> [[a]] -> Bool`. As an example, `find' 2 [[1,1,1,1], [3,3,3,3], [4,4,4,4]]` gives `False` and `find' 2 [[1,1,1,1], [3,3,3,3], [4,4,2,4]]` gives `True`. Here's how it works: First `map (elem x)` goes through each list (in the list of lists) and checks if `x` is an element. It produces a list of `Bool`s indicating whether `x` is in the corresponding list. Then `or` returns `True` if there's at least one `True` here.

Comment: List comprehensions always evaluate to lists. But from what I've understood, you want `find` to return a Bool: `Eq a => a -> [[a]] -> Bool`, right? I think it would be best if you try to explain what *you* think your code does. You can edit your question to do that, not in a comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a little renaming, I think you just wrote this:

```
find x yss = [ [ y | y <- ys, y `elem` ys ] | ys <- yss ]
```

I don't think that's what you meant to do. (In your code, you've got two variables named `x`, one shadowing the other.)

Your question doesn't state what tools you are or aren't allowed to use.

Clearly `elem` finds stuff in a list. And by "finds", I mean it returns a `Bool` indicating whether the target item is present or not. But how to handle a list of lists?

A list comprehension always returns a list, so if you were hoping for `find` to return a `Bool`, you don't want a list comprehension.

You can use `map` to apply `elem` to every list in the list of lists - but now you have a list of `Bool`s. There are two ways to deal with that. One slightly kludgy way is to use `elem` to see if the list contains `True` anywhere. But a more sane way is to use the built-in `or` function, which takes the logical-OR of a list of `Bool`s. (There is also a corresponding `and` function.)

```
find x yss = or (map (x `elem`) yss)
```

There's another way you can do this too; there's a built-in function called `any`, which applies a function to a list of stuff and returns `True` if the supplied function ever returns `True`. So you can do

```
find x yss = any (x `elem`) yss
```

Comment: I forgot to write, It should be returned in bool. But your functions helped so much, thank you so muuuuuuch : )

Comment: "if you were hoping for a `Bool`" -- `not null . concat $` ... ?

Comment: also, ``head $ [True | ys <- yss, y <- ys, x == y]++[False]``. :)